# Python: Size of a set when getting the Union of two sets?

Tags: python, size, jupyter, union

Hey I am trying to print the size of a set of the Union of two different sets and I am getting a length of three and there is way more than just three. What am I doing wrong?

print("Union :", set1 , set2)

set3 = ("Union :","set1","set2")

print(Len(set3))

Comment: `set3` is a *tuple* of three strings, you're not doing any union.

Answer (score 1):

To get a union of two sets, use `setA + setB`
If you want to eliminate duplicates in two sets, you need to use `set()`
and to find size (length) simply use `len()`

```
setA = (1,2,3,4)
setB = (3,4,5,6)
AUB = set(setA + setB)
nAUB = len(AUB)
print("A union B is:", AUB)
print("length of A union B is:",nAUB)
```

results:

```
A union B is: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
length of A union B is: 6
```

However the better way is to use the built in functions of sets `intersection()` and `union()`

```
setA = {1,2,3,4}
setB = {3,4,5,6}
setC = {5,6,7,8}
AuBuC = setA.union(setB, setC)
nAuBuC = len(AuBuC)
AnB = setA.intersection(setB)
nAnB = len(AnB)

print("AuBuC is:", AuBuC)
print("length of AuBuC is:",nAuBuC)
print("AnB is:", AnB)
print("nAnB is:", nAnB)
```

results:

```
AuBuC is: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
length of AuBuC is: 8
AnB is: {3, 4}
nAnB is: 2
```

Comment: print("Union :", set1 , set2)
set3 = set(set1 + set2)
length = len(set3)
print("A union B is:", set3)---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18624/1510025850.py in <module>
     30 
     31 print("Union :", set1 , set2)
---> 32 set3 = set(set1 + set2)
     33 length = len(set3)
     34 print("A union B is:", set3)
still having issues
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set'

Comment: @KellyWong it is because your set is in {}, if thats the case, you will need to use `union()` and `intersection()`